# public MWNumericArray(int rows, int columns, double[] realData) - How should I format my Double[]?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wish to create a MWNumericArray with 6 columns and 3000 rows. Each column should contain the measured values of a signal - meaning I have 6 signals with 3000 values each.

My question is: Should my double[] realData be the first values of the six signals, the second values of the six signals, and so on until value no. 3000?

An example using numbers for clarification:
Lets say signal one always have the value 1, signal two always have the value 2 and so on. 
Should realData then be 123456123456123456 and so on, with a total length of 3000*6?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: I think it should be as I have written! Is my interpretation correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWNumericArray__ctor_26.htm), your interpretation is correct, it will have 3000*6 elements with each element corresponding to a position in the row.